# SetWebHook on localhost in php

Tags: php, ssl

I want to use [SetWebHook](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#setwebhook) telegram bot API in php
But for that, I should use HTTPS certificate
I don't have a certificate
My question is this :
***can i use a self signed certificate in localhost and use setwebhook in telegram !?***


Would you mind show me a piece of php code for setwebhook !?
for example i write the following code :

```
<?php
$client = new Zelenin\Telegram\Bot\Api('someRandomToken');
try {

    if($update->message->text != '/next_event_datetime')
        exit;
    $response = $client->sendMessage([
        'chat_id' => $update->message->chat->id,
        'text' => $dateTime
    ]);

} catch (\Zelenin\Telegram\Bot\NotOkException $e) {

    //echo $e->getMessage();

}
```

**and my second question is :**
*Please explain to me how to set self signed certificate in Wamp*
There are many tutorials about that in the internet. but **they never worked**.
 because all of them are old.
Can anybody here that **show to me** how do i can use Self signed in Wamp !?

and could i use SetWebHook with a self signed certificate in localhost !?

Thanks...

Comment: Hi! I've the same problem .... use a self signed certificate in localhost and use setwebhook in telegram. Did you solved and how? I receive the following message ...... {"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Error: Bad webhook: Error: Ip is reserved"} .......  Any suggestions or useful link? Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I think you can not set webhook on localhost!
you can use self signed certificate (on host) and you should upload it when you want to set webhook. here is more information 
https://core.telegram.org/bots/self-signed